# How can i align replaced text file in python?

Tags: python, text, alignment

I changed part of column data, but when a i replaced that, the new file text, the columns in not align.
i send to you the files (input, output files), also you can see the following image.
Thank you for you answer!

Note: I read two columns in datar.csv

You can see the files: https://www.shorturl.at/luFX7

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datar.csv')
j=0
#input file
fin = open("input.txt", "rt")
#output file to write the result to
fout = open("output.txt", "wt")
#for each line in the input file
for line in fin:
    ori= df["data_o"][j]
    ori=str(ori)
    ree= df["data_r"][j]
    ree=str(ree)
    fout.write(line.replace(ori,ree))
    j=j+1
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

[I want it to be like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbC3n.png)

Comment: You'll need to write code, which have apparently not attempted to do.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question furthermore?

Comment: we need more info before we can answer your question. what have you tried? what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi, already update the data of the question, thank you for you answers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add an default width:

```
# e.g: 6 characters lenght
# [...] 
    line = line.replace(ori, ree)      # get line after convert
    line_original_width = len(line)    # get lenght of line
    if line_original_width < 6:        # check if fill is necessary
        fill = 6 - line_original_width # get amount of necessary fill
        line = (" " * fill) + line     # fill the left with space
    fout.write(line)                   # write all in the file
# [...]
```

Else, you can use the [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) to do the same things. But I can't show you an example because I'm not very good at.

Comment: Excuse me Sir, I cant solve the problem, in fact, with this routine, all file change of positition. But i appreciate your help really. greatings!

Comment: well, it become more complicated when the width is not the same everywhere. So I strongly suggest you to keep an default width, that will also make your code lightest and fastest. If you really want different width, I have some idea for you. Just contact me by discord. (123superfred#7476) @JoséJunco

Comment: oh!!! I understand my error. This code (with some twist) will work if you decode the file 1 number at time. In your case, you are decoding 1 lines by iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
There's a more complicated way for your code, but I'm sure it will work.
This program will make a default width for each column.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('datar.csv')
j=0

with open("input.txt", "rt") as fino:
    fin = fino.read()                      # !!!
fin = fin.split("\n")                      # !!!

fout = open("output.txt", "wt")
out = [[]] * len(fin)                      # !!!

# --- decode part ---
iter_count = 0                             # !!!
for line in fin:
    ori= df["data_o"][j]
    ori=str(ori)
    ree= df["data_r"][j]
    ree=str(ree)
    line = line.replace(ori, ree)
    line = line.split(" ")
    while "" in line: line.remove("")
    out[iter_count].append(line)
    iter_count += 1

# --- padding part ---
column_count = len(out[0])
row_count = len(out)
for column in range(column_count):
    maxl = []
    for row in range(row_count):
        maxl.append(len(out[row][column]))
    maxl = max(maxl) + 1
    for row in range(row_count):
        pad = " " * (maxl - len(out[row][column]))
        out[row][column] = pad + out[row][column]

# --- writting part ---
for row in out:
    for num in row:
        fout.write(num)
    fout.write("\n")
```

Watch-out, I modified the top part of your original code.

Mention me if you publish.

Comment: Sorry Sir,  but it is not that i m looking for, could you see the picture that i uploaded, thank you @123superfred . I appreciate your will.                                                                                                                                       Note: the code had some proble with string: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str...

Comment: what line? @Timo

Comment: Hi @123superfred, I wish something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbC3n.png

Comment: Hello @Timo. As you can see in your image, each column in your wanted result haven't the same width and haven't the same left padding. So you can't make the process automated. If you really want the output of the image, you will need to specify yourself the width of ALL the column of your file by hand.

Comment: Hi @123superfred, i try to do that, thank you for you help!